# Invalid response of JSON data from Django QuerySet

Tags: json, django, geojson, geodjango

With this query:

```
def high_hazard(request):
    reference_high = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='High')
    ids_high = reference_high.values_list('id', flat=True)

    flood_hazard = []
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties=['bldg_name', 'bldg_type'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    for myid in ids_high:
        getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
        response_high = BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom)
        get_hazard = geoj.encode(djf.decode(response_high.transform(900913)))
        flood_hazard.append(get_hazard)

    return HttpResponse(flood_hazard, content_type='application/json')
```

I was able to filter the `BuildingStructure` model based on `FloodHazard` type which is in this case with "high" value. Although it returns a JSON data, the output is messed up. I guess because it tests all the geometry from the `FloodHazard` model during loop. So, it returns several null set or empty and lots of FeatureCollection which makes it an invalid JSON data. The output of the query above is like this:

```
{
    "crs": null,
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

    ]
}{
    "crs": null,
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

    ]
}{
    "crs": null,
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        13974390.863509608,
                        1020340.6129766875
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3350,
            "properties": {
                "bldg_name": "",
                "bldg_type": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        13974400.312472697,
                        1020356.5477410051
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3351,
            "properties": {
                "bldg_name": "",
                "bldg_type": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As I test it with a JSON validator, it is invalid. So, is there a way to restructure(using underscore.js or jquery) this JSON to output like below? or I need to change my query?

```
{
    "crs": null,
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        13974390.863509608,
                        1020340.6129766875
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3350,
            "properties": {
                "bldg_name": "",
                "bldg_type": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPoint",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        13974400.312472697,
                        1020356.5477410051
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3351,
            "properties": {
                "bldg_name": "",
                "bldg_type": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and just ignore/remove all the FeatureCollection without values and group all with values.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/a1r6jfkz/) is the result of the query above for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return HttpResponse(flood_hazard, content_type='application/json')
```

Try

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(flood_hazard), content_type='application/json')
```

You will have to `import json` at the top.

Comment: Yes, it is now a valid JSON but outputs like this: `[
    "{\"crs\": null, \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": []}",..]`. How to remove the `[...]`?

Comment: `flood_hazard` is a list, so the json will also be a list, hence the `[]`

Comment: Yes, any idea how to change my query? Openlayers can't read the data.

Comment: How should the json be structured for it to accept the data?

Comment: It was stated in my question. Kindly check.

Comment: This might work `json.dumps(filter(lambda x:x["features"], flood_hazard)[0])`. You should improve the way your flood_hazard is populated instead of relying on this.

Comment: It returns an error `string indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73132/discussion-between-kedar-and-sachi-tekina).